# Comparing two pixels ( Color of them )

Tags: java, random, graphics, applet, drawing

Im making project for my uni, and I have a problem with one thing - everything works well, but there is bug with comparing colors of two pixels.
I have to count area of some figure, and I have to use MonteCarlo method. ( generate random points, count points in figure and out, calculete figure area )
And some points are counted well, some dont, I have no idea whats wrong, Im trying to solve that few hours...

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.image.BufferedImage;
import java.io.File;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Random;
import javax.imageio.ImageIO;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Runner extends JApplet{

private BufferedImage img;
public ArrayList<Point> w;
public ArrayList<Point> poza;
public BufferedImage output;

public void init(){

    try{
        img = ImageIO.read(new File("figura.gif"));
    } catch (IOException e){
        e.getStackTrace();
        System.err.println("Nie ma obrazkaXD");
    }

}

public void paint(Graphics g){
    w = new ArrayList<Point>();
    poza = new ArrayList<>();
    super.paint(g);
    Random random = new Random();
    int wys = img.getHeight();
    int szer = img.getWidth();
    g.drawImage(img, 0, 0, wys, szer, null);
    for (int i = 0; i < 1000; i++) {
        int x = random.nextInt(wys);
        int y = random.nextInt(szer);
        Point p = new Point(x,y);
        g.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        g.drawOval(y, x, 1, 1);
        Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(y, x));;
            if(c.equals(Color.BLACK)){
                w.add(p);
                g.setColor(Color.RED);
                g.drawOval(y, x, 1, 1);
            }else{
                poza.add(p);
            }
    }

float a = w.size();
float b = poza.size()+w.size();
float poleProstokata = wys*szer;
float pole = a/b*poleProstokata;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest you to switch the y and y Coordinate, because as described in the Oracle Documentation :

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/image/BufferedImage.html#getRGB(int,%20int)

The method getRGB takes the X first and the Y second, so you'll have to use

```
Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(x, y));
```

instead of

```
Color c = new Color(img.getRGB(y, x));;
```

and why dont use an int ? I mean, you always convert the returned int from getRGB to a color and compare it. But why dont create a int from the Color Black and compare it to the int returned from getRGB(x,y) ?

Heres what I suggest :

```
int black=Color.BLACK.getRGB();
```

at the beginning of your paint method

and in your loop :

```
int c=img.getRGB(y, x);
```

and compare them :

```
if (black==c) {
    //Do your stuff...
}
```